# Drawing diagonal lines in Crystal Reports XI

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report where the customer would like me to draw a couple diagonal arrows to point at a box on the report. Sounds easy enough, but Crystal does not appear to support diagonal lines. Is this true?

Answer (score 2):

that is true. You can create an arrow graphic though.